# Seed for srand() other than time() and getpid()

Tags: c

I am doing bare metal programming. I want to generate different random numbers across different executions, for which I have to seed the srand() function. but time(), gettimeofday() or getpid() is not an option. what else can I use as seed for srand() to get the desired result. 
Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

PS: Any other ways to get different random numbers across different runs other than rand/srand combinations are also welcome.

Comment: You can ask the user to type something, and then generate a seed based on how long it took them to type it. Using the microsecond part of the timing should have reasonable entropy.

Comment: What device is this for? Are there any hardware ports that might generate random "noise"?

Comment: If you have some non-volatile RAM seed it with the last random number from the previous run, which you store at that location.

Comment: unfortunately no. this is a test for verifying an soc that houses an arm processor.

Comment: If the soc has an A/D converter, that can be used.

Comment: Add a hardware RNG. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator

Comment: if your SOC contains a real time clock, then you should be able to read that clock value to obtain the needed seed value

Comment: I am not clear about ur exact requirement. Why you need a seed value other than time? Try - declare a variable , use it's address to seed

Comment: @AjithCNarayanan Thanks that worked. I cant use time as I dont run the app on an OS. Its bare metal.

Comment: "I cant use time as I dont run the app on an OS. Its bare metal" --> A bare metal machine can still provide a working `time()`.  It sounds like you can use `time()`, because it is not provided (non-compliant C) or because it always returns -1.  Does `clock()` work on your machine?